# How to get azure app service eventlog.xml from pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to get the last x lines of the eventlog.xml from an app service staging slot?

I'm looking for a way of programmatically getting the reason why a slot swap failed.

Currently all we get in the azure devops pipeline when the swap fails is this from running `az webapp deployment slot swap`:

```
ERROR: Cannot swap slots for site 'web-1-webapp' because the application initialization in 'stagingslot' slot either took too long or failed. Please check AppInit module configuration or try using swap with preview if application initialization time is very long.
INFO: Command ran in 58.707 seconds (init: 0.619, invoke: 58.088)
```

It would be useful to bring back the reason for the failure which is usually found in the eventlog.xml. I can only see ways to do this through the azure portal either via kudo or diagnose and solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've answered my own question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-log-download

The az cli command `az webapp log download` can get all the logs as a zip file